# ¿Cómo mover puntos creados en el evento Paint de un PictureBox de acuerdo a la imagen según se haga mas grande, chico o se mueva?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, visual-studio-2017

Buen día.

Tengo un proyecto en windows forms C# en donde tengo un elemento PictureBox, dentro de este elemento en su evento Paint dibujo un rectángulo que contiene una imagen.

El rectángulo lo puedo mover, hacer mas chico y grande para darle a la imagen un efecto de movimiento y resize.

Ahora estoy dibujando puntos que se unen mediante líneas para dibujar un polígono en el contorno de la imagen.

Lo que quiero hacer es que cuando haga mas grande o mas chico el rectángulo y al mover, los puntos y líneas también se ajusten de acuerdo al contorno de la imagen que contiene el rectángulo.

El rectángulo que contiene la imagen lo muevo de posicion con el evento MouseMove y lo hago mas grande y mas chico con el evento MouseWheel.

Los puntos los genero con el evento click del PictureBox.

[image: Imagen Ilustrativa]

Codigo donde agrego la imagen al rectangulo

```
Rectangle rec = new Rectangle((PictureEdit1.Width / 2), (PictureEdit1.Width / 2), imagen.Size.Width, imagen.Size.Height);
```

Dibujo el rectangulo con la imagen, los puntos y lineas en el evento Paint

```
Graphics g = e.Graphics;
g.DrawImage(imagen, rec);

Pen skyBluePen = new Pen(Brushes.Blue);
Pen skyBorderBluePen = new Pen(Brushes.DodgerBlue);
skyBluePen.LineJoin = LineJoin.Bevel;
skyBorderBluePen.LineJoin = LineJoin.Bevel;
skyBluePen.Width = 3F;
skyBorderBluePen.Width = 3F;

 foreach (LineaItem item in listPointLine)
 {
      e.Graphics.DrawLine(skyBluePen, item.PuntoInicial, item.PuntoFinal);
      e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(skyBorderBluePen, item.PuntoInicial.X, item.PuntoInicial.Y, 3, 3);
 }
```

Como obtengo el nuevo tamaño del rectangulo (resize) sin perder la forma de la imagen, el ancho y alto deben de ser proporcional al tamaño original.

```
float percent = (new List<float> { (float)nuevoAncho / (float)Imagen.Width, (float)nuevoAncho  / (float)Imagen.Height }).Min();
Size resultSize = new Size((int)Math.Floor(Imagen.Width * percent), (int)Math.Floor(Imagen.Height * percent));
```

Ya investigue mucho y no he encontrado nada al respecto, realmente el detalle que tengo es al hacer resize. Modifico las coordenadas de los puntos pero se salen del contorno de la imagen.

Espero haberme explicado, saludos y gracias.

Comment: Los puntos los guardas en una lista?

Comment: Si, los guardo en una lista.